# Default value set, but not used

Tags: csom, spfield, default-value

I am creating a field through the following xml:

```
<Field
    Name="FieldName"
    StaticName="FieldName"
    DisplayName="FieldName"
    Required="FALSE"
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    ID="{12345678-1234-4321-1234-123456789012}"
    Group="FieldGroup"
    Type="Choice"
    Format="Dropdown"
    SourceID="http://schemas.name.nl/">
        <Default>FirstChoice</Default>
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>FirstChoice</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>SecondChoice</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>ThirdChoice</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>    
</Field>
```

I am using the following function for this:

```
CSOM.Field field = web.CreateField(Xml);
```

This all goes correctly, however the default value is not fully coming through. If I create a listitem with this field on it, the value is empty at first, while I should have expected the default value here.

In the list settings the default value is set correctly as FirstChoice. But only when I open the list settings and press okay (While not changing anything!) When I do this and then create another list item, the value is set with the default value right away.

Can anyone explain where this behavior is coming from and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
<Field 
    Name="FieldName"
    DisplayName="FieldName"
    Required="FALSE"
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    ID="{12345678-1234-4321-1234-123456789012}"
    Group="FieldGroup"
    Type="Choice">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>FirstChoice</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>SecondChoice</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>ThirdChoice</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>    
  <Default>FirstChoice</Default>
</Field>
```

Comment: That worked for me, putting it outside of the <CHOICES> tag
i find it so hard to get documentation for this stuff!